# peer to peer RTP call setup in asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I want to set up call between to peers in asterisk in which RTP flow is between two peers when internal calls.I don't  want to go RTP flow from peer-asterisk-peer.I want to setup RTP flow like peer-peer.My sip.conf setup is like this.`

```
    [1001]
    type=friend
    host=dynamic
    nat=no
    ; qualify=no
    dtmf=rfc2833
    secret=1234
    callerid=1001 <1001>
    directrtpsetup=yes
    context=test_rtp
    disallow=all
    allow=g729
    allow=alaw
    allow=ulaw
```

Second peer 1002 is same.In this case RTP goes through asterisk.What changes should made to get peer to peer RTP call setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're part of the way there already with the

```
directrtpsetup=yes
```

configuration option.

For this to work, you'll also need to add the following line:

```
directmedia=yes
```

You also have to ensure you do *not* use any of the following `Dial()` command options:

```
"t", "T", "h", "H", "w", "W" or "L"
```

... since Asterisk must remain in the audio path to handle these.

Lastly, *both* ends of the call must support and be configured for `directmedia`.  If one end is not or does not, then Asterisk will remain in the audio path.

***further reading***

- http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+SIP+media+path
- http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+sip+canreinvite

---

*(if this answer addresses your question, please 'accept' it so that other users can benefit from it.  thanks!)*